# Creating arraylist from a string with shared preferences

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I want to know how to take a simple string that is being saved in shared preferences but then save each one of those strings and display them into an array list. The user will save the string once a day. And I want the strings to display as an array list. Here's the code for what I'm working with. I have "physical_fragment.java"(SAVES THE DATA) & "MainActivity.java"(LOADS THE DATA).

PHSYICAL_FRAGMENT.JAVA

```
    public void save(View view){

    Date date = new Date();
    String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("result",String.format(stringDate, date) + " - " + text_view5.getText().toString());

    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
    resultPhysical= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String result= sharedPreferences.getString("result",DEFAULT);

    if (result.equals(DEFAULT))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else

        Toast.makeText(this, "Load Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    resultPhysical.setText(result);


    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? I only see a description of what you're trying to do but not where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I haven't tried to turn it into an array list because I have no idea how. I don't even know where to begin. I am new to coding :(

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, could you edit you're post to add one (or more) examples of such strings and how the array list should be after filling it?

Comment: When it saves and loads the "result", I don't want there to only be one result. I want each of the results to save and show up as an array list

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for that.

To convert a list of strings to JSON to be stored in preferences you use this:

```
List<String> list = ...

Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(list, type);
```

and store `json` in `SharedPreferences` using `putString`.

To read from `SharedPreferences` you use something like this:

```
String result = sharedPreferences.getString("result", DEFAULT);

Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
List<String> list = gson.fromJson(result, type);
```

Comment: a list of strings, of course :-) you have a list of strings that user has added, right?

Comment: wait. am i supposed to put all of that in my mainactivity? --sorry im new to coding

Comment: as two methods, why not. i'm affraid that SO is not best place to lear coding from scratch. we'll answer your questions, but it's hard to teach someone coding from the beginning :-/

Comment: I understand, as I am completely lost with the code you have given me lolol. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follows:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences.edit();

ArratList<String> dataList;
String data = "";
for(String itemData:dataList){
    data = itemData + String.format(stringDate, date) + " - " +  text_view5.getText().toString()+ "/";
    editor.putString(data);
}

editor.commit();
```

Now get the string from Shared preference and split it.

```
String result= sharedPreferences.getString("result",DEFAULT);
String[] splited = str.split("/");
```

This helps with out having support of Libraries which can effect size of apk file

Comment: I have just written on text document.You can edit this.I made some change in code.check it once

Comment: data = itemData + String.format(stringDate, date) + " - " +  text_view5.getText().toString()+ "/";

Comment: I get an error on "(String itemData:dataList){" and "editor.putString(data);"